# Unobtrusive validation not working after adding checkboxes to the form in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I want to make checkboxes optional, whether to be checked or not. But when I add a checkbox on my view it will make unobtrusive validation to be stopped. But when I remove the checkbox from my view, unobtrusive validations works fine. What's the problem ?
I am adding checkbox like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.features.safetyfeature.Airbag)
```

All the model values are correct.

Comment: Same problem here.  I noticed that by default, it adds the data-val-required and data-val attributes to the checkbox by default.  When those are there, the problems you describe happen.  When I remove them using the inspector, the form validates as desired.  In summary, it looks like CheckBoxFor adds the required attributes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem & posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320289/mvc-checkboxfor-causing-unobtrusive-validation-to-be-bypassed?noredirect=1#comment28618658_19320289). Currently I don't have a solution to the problem, but I did find a workaround.  Instead of using `Html.CheckBoxFor` I used `Html.CheckBox` like so:

```
@Html.CheckBox("Employee.Active")
```

I gave it the same name as the CheckBoxFor that was created by the razor view.  This is now working as I expected but I consider it a workaround rather that a solution, and I have no idea what's actually causing the problem!

Comment: This worked for me.   It's not ideal but it solves the problem and I can live with it.